# Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to open the Eclipse Marketplace from Eclipse Neon 64-bit. Whenever I try to select Help-> Eclipse Marketplace, I get the following message:

```
Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace

Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Connection failed
```

In the error log:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem$3.handleEvent(AbstractContributionItem.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p.
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand$5.run(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.stream(CachingTransport.java:244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.AbstractP2TransportFactory.invokeStream(AbstractP2TransportFactory.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory$1.stream(TransportFactory.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.FallbackTransportFactory$FallbackTransport.primaryFailed(FallbackTransportFactory.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.FallbackTransportFactory$FallbackTransport.stream(FallbackTransportFactory.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:136)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.connectSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1084)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1071)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Contains: Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.connectSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1084)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1071)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Go to your `Update Sites` list and clean it, keep only the official Neon sites and disable everything else. Also, check your `Preferences -> Network`

Comment: Nope, disabled all of the Juno sites and still didn't work. I also set the Active Connection to Manual and cleared SOCKS.

Comment: Did you try to fetch http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p in your browser? I get the catalog XML. What do you get?

Comment: Is your firewall preventing Eclipse from talking to `marketplace.eclipse.org`?

Comment: @Jim Garrison When I go to the marketplace site, I just see a bunch of HTML. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: @discipline I turned firewall completely off, still not working.

Comment: it's XML not HTML, but that is what you should see, which means you are connecting to the server.

Comment: @SSung2710 turn off your anti-virus and try again. Also, try using the IPv4 Java environment variable `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the anti-virus worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you should change proxy setting in eclipse:

1. Windows --> Preferences --> General --> Network Connection
2. Change 'Active Provider' to Manual